# How to get metatable set by lua from Lua C API

Tags: c, lua, lua-api

Lua:

```lua
a = {
    b = "c",
    d = {
        e = "f",
        g = "h"    
    }
}
setmetatable(a.d, {__ismt = true})

cfun(a) --call C function to iterate over table a
```

C:

```c
int cfun(lua_State *L)
{
    lua_pushnil(L);
    while (lua_next(L, -2) != 0)
    {
        // iterate over table

        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
}
```

How do you know if there is a metatable when the host client iterates over the table?  And then how do you get the metatable?

Comment: [`lua_getmetatable`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_getmetatable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is in a form of a tree, and you need to traverse the tree in iterative mode. Lua already has a stack implementation, so this makes the job easier.

- On entrance, the stack has the table at top, you will push a `nil` element since `lua_next()` will consume one element from the stack before checking the table. So the stack will look like `table -> nil`.
- Next, we are calling `lua_next()` which will consume one element from the stack and will add two new key-value pair from the table. The stack will look like  `table -> key -> value`. If there is no next element, the return value of the call is 0.
- If the return value is 1, and the value on stack is a nested table, you will push nil on the stack, so now the stack will look like `table -> key -> table -> nil`. Now you are almost like on the begining, so with the loop, you will start traversing the nested table.
- if the return value is 1, and if the value is not table, to your stuff with the value
- if the return value is 0, we can check if this was a meta table. After the check,  you will pop the value and check if the stack is `table -> key` or `any -> key`. If the second element on the stack is not a table, you have finished the traversing and you will break the loop.

Here is the `C` code that implements the algorithm. I have left the `printf` in order to help debugging. The `printf()` should be removed.

```
static int cfun(lua_State *L)
{
    luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);
    lua_pushnil(L);        // Add extra space for the first lua_next to pop
    int loop=1;
    do {
        if ( lua_next(L,-2) != 0 ) {
            if (lua_istable(L,-1)) {
                printf("Table [%s] \n", lua_tostring(L, -2));
                lua_pushnil(L); // Start iterating this sub-table
            } else {
                // The Key and Value are on the stack. We can get their type
                printf("(%s - %s)\n", 
                    lua_tostring(L, -2),
                    lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -1)));
                lua_pop(L,1);
            }
        } else {
            printf("table finished, still on stack (%s -> %s -> %s)\n",
                    lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -3)),
                    lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -2)),
                    lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, -1)));
            if (lua_getmetatable(L,-1)) {
                // The table has metatable. Now the metatable is on stack
                printf("Metatable detected\n");
                lua_pop(L,1); // remove the metatable from stack
            }
            lua_pop(L,1); // Pop the current table from stack
            if (!lua_istable(L, -2)) {
                loop = 0; // No more tables on stack, breaking the loop
            }
        }
    } while (loop);
    lua_pop(L,1); // Clear the last element
    lua_pushnumber(L,0); // Return 0
    return 1;
}
```